# Using aggregated data from a database with data from another

Tags: regression, econometrics, measurement-error, endogeneity, errors-in-variables

Let's say I have two databases, in the first (DB1) there is individual data on how much people trust in the government ($X_{j,r}$), and on the second (DB2) there is individual data on how much people donate $Y_{i,r}$  (I use $j$ instead of $i$ to make clear the individuals observed in both databases are not the same).

So my theory (in this example) is that in regions with lower trust in government, people donate more. So I want to run:

> REG: $Y_{i, r} = \beta X_{r} + \gamma_{r} Z_{r} + \gamma_{i} Z_{i}$

So I calculate the mean of $X_{j,r}$ in DB1, and use it as variable in DB2 to run the OLS above.

My questions are:

1. Do I need to correct the standard errors of REG to account for the fact that $X_{r}$  is imperfectly estimated?
2. Should I weight REG for the standard errors of the mean of $X_{j,r}$ (give more weight to $r$ for which $X_{r}$ is better estimated)?

Comment: You are correct that you will have measurement error in X, which will lead to [endogeneity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endogeneity_%28applied_statistics%29). This causes biased (closer to 0) parameter estimates. Weighted least squares is a good idea, but will only adjust for relative uncertainty b/t the regions. You may be able to use [errors in variables regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models).